# The fastest way to get huge array of random numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, probability-theory

I'm making a game. There are lootboxes. Player can open at the same time thousands of lootboxes, and each lootbox have several items.
I have an extension method that returns an array of random elements:

```
 static public IEnumerable<T> Random<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int countOfRandomElements)
    {
        var collectionSize = collection.Count();
        for (int id = 0; id < countOfRandomElements; id++)
            yield return collection.ElementAt(random.Next(collectionSize));            
    }
```

And as you might have guessed when player opens to many lootboxes at once (3k+) heavy lags begin.
Collection size is changing from 3 items to 100 approximately. So I decided to try writing a method that will randomly assign number to each object from the collection. Equity of this number is easy to find. But I can't correctly calculate standard deviation because it's changes for different size of collection.

Now I'm looking for any clue in probability theory, but my research has not yielded any results so far.
Could anyone help me please?

---

Update. Thanks to comments I make small change. Now it works much more faster. I didn't realize that LINQ .ElementAt method is to slow until replace it with .ToArray() . 3 millions of objects with help of this method are generating about 1.5 sec now instead 1 minute as it was with .ElementAt for collection of 30 elements. Simple solution - fascinating execution time impromvent.

```
    static public IEnumerable<T> Random<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int countOfRandomElements)
    {
        var array = collection.ToArray();
        var collectionSize = array.Length;
        for (int id = 0; id < countOfRandomElements; id++)
            yield return array[random.Next(collectionSize)];
    }
```

Comment: Should the content of the lootboxes change each time they are opened, or should it be the same?

Comment: One of the way is to avoid using method `ElementAt` as it has `O(n)`. Try to use like that `collection.ToArray()[random.Next(collectionSize)];`

Comment: @StepUp `IEnumerable` doesn't have an indexer....

Comment: @ZoharPeled if we `IEnumerable` will cast `ToArray` and then apply indexer, then is it good idea? Thanks for your comment! :)

Comment: @StepUp you would of course do this outside of the loop `var collectionArray = collection.ToArray();` once and `var collectionSize = collectionArray.Length;` and then within the loop only `yield return collectionArray[random.Next(collectionSize)];` in order to enumerate only once ;)

Comment: @HedgehogNSK if your main concern is a possible lag why not generate the entire array of random numbers in a background thread and just wait for the result?

Comment: Thanks for advice about cast ToArray. But it didn't helps much. As I wrote in my question the problem is that I need to call generation for thousands and hundred of thousands items.

@derHugo for example, if player will open 100k boxes with 5 items in each, than game will be stunned on about 1 minute. 
I can't make calculations in another thread because I need to animate openning of chest. In this way I need to show something to user before content will be generated.

I will be moving in way of generating random numbers with fixed sum and distributing it between items collection.

Comment: @HedgehogNSK if you e.g. know beforehand how many boxes there will be I would already beforehand at any point during the gameplay in a background thread prepare the array for the moment when you need it later. Ofcourse we don't know your exact use-case so it is quite hard to tell what option would be the best fit for you ... I mean even if you open a lot of things at once .. you could probably still display stuff in the UI one by one right? and dealing with `500.000` operations sounds of course quite huge but shouldn't take over a minute ... depends a bit what you do with that data later ;)

Comment: Oops. I was wrong. Cast to Array significantly improves the speed of generations. Thanks a lot. :D Now generation of 3kk objects takes long 1520 ms.

Comment: @derHugo thanks for your response. I understand what you are suggesting. I need to find where I can add calculation in new thread.

Comment: It sounds like your issue might rather lie in what exactly you are doing with the data afterwards